# Filter the Solr autosuggestion in Hybris

Tags: solr, sap-commerce-cloud

I am trying to implement Solr context filtering to filter auto-suggestion result based on the category value. Autosuggestion has been implemented with `SpellCheckComponent`.

**schema.xml**

```
<field name="autosuggest" type="text_spell" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="true" />
<field name="autosuggest_en" type="text_spell_en" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="true" />
<field name="autosuggest" type="text_spell" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="true" />
<copyField source="autosuggest" dest="autosuggest_en" />
<fieldType name="text_spell" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
            <analyzer>
                <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory" />
                <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory" />
            </analyzer>
</fieldType>
<field name="autosuggest_en" type="text_spell_en" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="true" />
        <fieldType name="text_spell_en" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
            <analyzer>
                <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory" />
                <filter class="solr.PatternReplaceFilterFactory" pattern="(['’])" replacement=" " />
                <filter class="solr.EnglishMinimalStemFilterFactory" />
                <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" words="lang/stopwords_en.txt" ignoreCase="true" />
                <filter class="solr.ManagedStopFilterFactory" managed="en" />
                <filter class="solr.SynonymFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" synonyms="synonyms.txt"/>
                <filter class="solr.ManagedSynonymFilterFactory" managed="en" />
                <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory" />
                <filter class="solr.TrimFilterFactory" />
                <filter class="solr.RemoveDuplicatesTokenFilterFactory" />
            </analyzer>
</fieldType>
<dynamicField name="*_string_mv" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="true" />
```

**solrConfig.xml**

```
<searchComponent name="suggest" class="solr.SpellCheckComponent">
    <lst name="spellchecker">
        <str name="name">categorydic</str>
        <str name="classname">org.apache.solr.spelling.suggest.Suggester</str>
        <str name="lookupImpl">org.apache.solr.spelling.suggest.fst.AnalyzingInfixLookupFactory</str>
        <str name="dictionaryImpl">org.apache.solr.spelling.suggest.DocumentDictionaryFactory</str>
        <str name="field">autosuggest_en</str>
        <str name="contextField">allCategories_string_mv</str>
        <str name="buildOnStartup">false</str>
        <str name="buildOnCommit">false</str>
        <str name="suggestAnalyzerFieldType">text_spell_en</str>
        <str name="indexPath">${solr.core.dataDir}/suggesttest</str>
    </lst>
    </searchComponent>
    <requestHandler name="/suggest" class="solr.SearchHandler" startup="lazy">
        <lst name="defaults">
            <str name="spellcheck">true</str>
            <str name="spellcheck.dictionary">en</str>
            <str name="spellcheck.onlyMorePopular">true</str>
            <str name="spellcheck.count">5</str>
            <str name="spellcheck.collate">true</str>
        </lst>
        <arr name="components">
            <str>suggest</str>
        </arr>
    </requestHandler>
```

http://localhost:8983/solr/master_Product/suggest?spellcheck=true&spellcheck.build=true&spellcheck.dictionary=categorydic&wt=json&spellcheck.q=mytest&spellcheck.cfq=harddiskcategory

When I am hitting this URL with `spellcheck.dictionary=categorydic`, `spellcheck.cfq=harddiskcategory`,`spellcheck.q=mytest` it won't filter the result. I am getting all the match of **mytest**

Any clue?

---

**Edit:**
Solr Version: 5.3.0
Hybris Vesion: 6.0

Answer (score -1):

You have to look at the solr configurationa t the impex files. Something like **solr.impex**. There you have the possibility to configure how solr should act. I think there you could also configure the autosugesstion thing.

Comment: No it's not about configuration in the Hybris. OOTB Hybris doesn't support context filtering.